# CSS Grid and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First time posting in Code Review! I have started learning front-end development to complement my UI design skillset and am starting with CSS Grid and bootstrap.

Have a look at the snippets. I think the 2 work quite well, using CSS Grid for layout and the Bootstrap library for things like buttons, forms and navs etc.

Can you let me know if there is anything I can do to make my code more scalable and more toward production standard?

Thanks!

```css
body{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo{
    height: 30px;
    margin: 50px;
}

.container-fluid{
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
        "L R"
}


.left-side{
    grid-area: L;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.right-side{
    grid-area: R;
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, rgb(255, 0, 0,0.8), rgba(167,0,0,0.8));
    height: 100vh;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}



.right-inner{
    margin: 40% auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
}


.welcome{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "UniversNext", sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.cust-name{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "UniversNext", sans-serif;

}


.log-in{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    float: left;
}


.log-in:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #253038;
}

.log-in:active{
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #253038;
}

.log-in:focus{
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #253038;
}


.password{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.form-control{
    min-height: 38px;
}

.col-form-label-sm{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}



p{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;

}

a{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
}

a:hover{
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <title>site</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="left-side">
                <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
            </div>

            <!-- Right hand side -->

            <div class="right-side">
                            <div class="right-inner">
                                <h3 class="welcome">Welcome back <span class="cust-name">Alan!</span></h3>    
                                        <form>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control password" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <input class="btn btn-primary log-in" id="log-in" type="submit" value="Log in">
                                                    <p>Forgot your password?</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form> 
                                        
                                        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register</a></p>
                            </div>    
            </div>

            <!-- right hand side End -->
    </div>
</body>









</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Semantics and UX

You can adjust a few things that will improve the overall UX of your login-page:

### Document outline / structure

To improve the overall structure of your document use sectioning elements like `header`, `main`, `section` etc.:

```
<header class="left-side">
    <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
</header>

<main class="right-side">
    <h1>Welcome back</h1>
</main>
```

Keep in mind that headings are hierarchical from `h1` to `h6` in HTML. So it might make sense to have a `h3` as the first heading in a sectioning element, but it really depends on your content.

See also on MDN ["Sections and Outlines of an HTML5 Document"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document).

### Don't use `placeholder` as `labels`

I know, it's easy to set up and it instantly looks nice. But this is not the intended use-case. See the specs:

> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint
>   (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user
>   with data entry when the control has no value.
>
> The placeholder attribute should not be used as
>   a replacement for a label. For a longer hint or
>   other advisory text, place the text next to the
>   control.

<sup>From W3C ["4.10.5.3.10. The placeholder attribute"](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute)</sup>

There a are a lot of downsides of using `placeholders` as  `labels`, like:

- once something is typed into a field, you have to rely on the short-term memory of the user, to remember which field was which
- the form can get ambiguous as soon as you have pre-filled elements as well
- it reduces accessibility and usability for users with cognitive, mobility, fine motor skill or vision impairments

Instead use `label`-elements:

```
<label>
    Email
    <input type="email">
</label>

<label for="form-email">Email</label>
<input id="form-email" type="email">
```

You can read more about this on the Nielson Norman Group ["Placeholders in Form Fields Are Harmful
"](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/) or on Smashing Magazine ["Don’t Use The Placeholder Attribute"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/).

### "*Forgot your password*"-Link

This is a paragraph, which will do nothing, when the user clicks on it. Make it an anchor, that takes the user to the "forgot password"-form:

```
<a href="">Forgot your password?</a>
```

You don't necessarily need to wrap it into an `p`-element, but that's just optional.

## Indentation

I would reduce the amount of indentation to make the source more readable. It also looks like the `form`-element is nested within the `h3`. This could be improved:

```
<h3 class="welcome">Welcome back <span class="cust-name">Alan!</span></h3>

<form>
</form>
```

On the other hand some nested elements could be indented to increase readability:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

### Don't limit the page's size

… unless there's a very specific use-case of your UI.

You set `overflow: hidden;` on the `body`-element. Then you set `height: 100vh;` on the container that holds all content. That can work, if you have a fluid layout that adopts to all screen sizes. But usually it's a bad idea as you don't know how high the viewport is, whether the user zoomed in etc. You see it already, when running the snippet – *You can't scroll down to use the login form.* This should be fixed.

Comment: I was thinking of posting my second grid layout for review here. I hope I get as thorough a review as above. Nice one insertusernamehere !